# Save Bash Shell Script Output To a File with a String

Tags: linux, bash

I have an executable that takes a file and outputs a line.
I am running a loop over a directory:

```
for file in $DIRECTORY/*.png
do    
    ./eval $file >> out.txt
done
```

The output of executable does not contain the name of the file.
I want to append the file name with each output.

**EDIT1**

Perhaps, I could not explain it correctly 
I want the name of the file and the output of the program as well, which is processing the same file, Now I am doing following

```
for file in $DIRECTORY/*.png
do    
     echo -n $file >> out.txt
     or
     printf "%s" "$file" >> out.txt

    ./eval $file >> out.txt
done
```

For both new line is inserted

Comment: `echo -n $file >> out.txt`?

Comment: Please refer to http://www.sscce.org to clarify your question.

Comment: @Joachim, it works, but -n does not stop the insertion of new line, any ideas?

Comment: perhaps, my version of bash does not recognize -n

Comment: If your shell does not recognize `-n`, try: `printf "%s" "$file" >> out.txt`

Comment: does not help, the new line is inserted anyway, what I am doing is that I am writing two lines, the first one `printf "%s" "$file" >> out.txt` followed by  `./eval $file >> out.txt`

Comment: Most probably your eval script is inserting the newline. Can you try just printf, comment the eval

Comment: Is this `./eval` program your own program? Do you, in that program, print *leading* newlines?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, what you want is:

- get the name of the file,
- ...and the output or the program processing the file (in your case, eval),
- ...on the same line. And this last part is your problem.

Then I'd suggest composing a single line of text (using echo), comprising:

- the name of the file, this is the $file part,
- ...followed by a separator, you may not need that but it may help further processing of the result. I used ":". You can skip this part if this is not interesting for you,
- ...followed by the output of the program processing the file: this is the $(...) construct

  echo $file ":" $(./eval $file) >> out.txt

...and finally appending this line of text to a file, you got that part right.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the original problem?

Answer (score -1):

please use like this

```
echo -n `echo ${file}|tr -d '\n'`  >> out.txt
```

OR

```
newname=`echo ${file}|tr -d '\n'`

echo -n $newname >> out.txt
```

Comment: could you paste the code here , which you are trying .

if its possible ,please  explain the problem little bit more